# Sharepoint 2010: publishing reports?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, reporting

I know that Sharepoint 2010 will store almost everything into its databases. We have a reporting application and we would like to publish our reports into Sharepoint 2010. We don't have any integration kit for Sharepoint 2010. What options do we have? Can we publish our reports into Sharepoint database or how this should be implemented?

Comment: What format is your report in? SQL server reporting services? Crystal reports? Excel reports?

Comment: Business Objects Web Intelligence and Crystal Reports. SAP Business Objects does not provide an integration kit for MOSS 2010. We can publish into file location or FTP server. How to use these for Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I can't tell if you want a programmatic solution or not.  Either way, you can store your reports into a SharePoint Document Library

A) By manually uploading the reports to the SharePoint Document Library 
or 
B) By creating a simple app or web service to do the job for you

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=297